# Is Basic Auth still needed when CORS enabled in Spring-Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, cors, basic-authentication

In my Controller, which is build with using spring-boot, I've enable CORS only for my server and localhost whit this annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:8080", "https://www.somepage.com"}, maxAge = 3600)
```

This is working fine. But now I'm not sure, if it's also needed, to add basic authentication for the REST API. As far as I understood, the only call the REST API is accepting now, is my own server and localhost, and that's why, I think it's not needed. But I was not able to figure out, if this is a bad practice or not.

Do You recommend to use basic auth too for the REST API even when CORS is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**.

---

The Same Origin Policy is a feature built into browsers that prevents an attacker's JavaScript running on the attacker's website from reading the response to an HTTP request from the victim's browser to the targetted website.

This stops the attacker from stealing data from the targetted website using the credentials belonging to the victim.

(To some degree. There are other kinds of attacks.)

CORS is a tool that *relaxes* this rule so that when you to allow another site to access that data (either using the user's credentials or because it is just public data), it can.

---

Note that I said "a feature built into browsers". It isn't built into other tools.

An attacker can still make HTTP requests with their code, or tools like Postman and curl, or their own web browser.

**Neither the Same Origin Policy nor CORS are substitutes for authentication and authorization.**

Answer (score 0):

CORS is a mechanism implemented in browsers and it will not prevent me to access your API with `curl`. Therefore, secure your API if you need it to stay secure.